# How to execute multiple if statements optimally in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I have defined a function which executes multiple if-statements. although it executes only if-statements but not executing else statements in a flow in which it is defined. What I have to do to execute else statements just after the respective call of related if statements.

```
  func levelTwo() {

    if firstText.text == "A"
    {
        hintLabel.text = "\(self.hintsTwo[1])"
        self.firstValid.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "check")
    }
    else {
        self.firstValid.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "markQ")
    }

    if SecFirstText.text == "A" && secSecText.text == "C"
    {
        hintLabel.text = "\(self.hintsTwo[2])"
        self.secondValid.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "check")
    }
    else {
        self.secondValid.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "markQ")
    }

    if thiFirstText.text == "C" && thiSecText.text == "A" && thiThirdText.text == "T"
    {
        hintLabel.text = "\(self.hintsTwo[3])"
        self.thirdValid.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "check")
    }
    else {
        self.thirdValid.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "markQ")
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks like the same operation done many times with differing sets of data. That's the use case for a for loop. Make a data structure that holds these letters and hints, and loop over it, running a single copy of this code on that data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use switch with [tuples](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID448):

```
switch(firstText.text, thiSecText.text) {
    case ("A", _):
        //First text equal a, second text equal anything
        break
    case ("A", "C"):
        //First text A, second text B
        break
    case (_, "B"):
        //First text anything, second text B
        break
    default:
        break
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use this construction (simplified, but the core idea is visible):

```
class MyClass {
    var firstText = "One"
    var secondText = "Two"
    var thirdText = "Three"
    var firstImage: UIImage?
    var secondImage: UIImage?
    var thirdImage: UIImage?
}

let instance = MyClass()

let keyPaths = [\MyClass.firstText:\MyClass.firstImage,
                \MyClass.secondText:\MyClass.secondImage,
                \MyClass.thirdText:\MyClass.thirdImage]

for (text, image) in keyPaths {
    if instance[keyPath: text] == "Two" {
        instance[keyPath: image] = UIImage()
    }
}
```